# My laptop not waking up after suspend

Tags: nvidia, suspend

I am having problem with my laptop which is runs ubuntu. Before I tell the problem here what I have in this laptop:

[Here is a neofetch pic(Asus X550VX)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IENYl.png)

So my problem is whenever I suspend my laptop it is not waking up again. I have to cut power for reboot it. here how it's look when it doesn't boot up:

[This is how it's look when I try to open after suspend it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqm92.jpg)

When I disable the GPU from NVIDIA X server it's works just fine but I really need my GPU. I also use windows on this laptop and I run ubuntu on my desktop(cpu and gpu is amd) I don't have any problem with those.

Comment: I am afraid that didn't work on me. Everything is still same. But thanks for your answer anyway. I had different problems when I use those steps on my laptop

Comment: You may want to edit your question and add the details of what "different problems" you are having.